# Removing dynamically created EditText from Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, android-edittext

My activity's layout contains a ListView type list which I've created dynamically (I didn't use an actual ListView). An add button is clicked, which creates a row containing an EditText and a delete button. The user's input is saved from the EditText into a SQLite table. Everything works aside from the delete button. I'm able to delete the view, but the data remains in the table. The emulator crashes on click of the delete button.

The table contains only an "_Id" column and "Comment" column. I'm a beginner in Android development, but especially inexperienced with SQLite; this is my first attempt.
Sorry if I've added too much code. I added the whole datasource class, but felt like I was going overboard. If you'd like to see more, just let me know, cause I never know if all that I've attached is useful or not.

Here is my method that saves a row's EditText input to the database.

```
public Comment createComment(String comment) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);
    long insertId = database.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
            values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
            allColumns, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newComment;
}
```

And here is my attempt to remove a row's data from the database.

```
public void deleteComment(String comment) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);

    database.delete(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT
            + " = " + values, null);

}
```

This is my Comment class. Not sure if it was necessary considering the comment is just a string in an EditText. I borrowed a lot of code from an online source, so I'm not completely clear on how it should all be put together.

```
public class Comment {
private long id;
private String comment;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

// Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
@Override
public String toString() {
    return comment;
}
```

}

Here's some code from my main activity which dynamically creates the views.

```
// onClick handler for the "Add new" button;
public void onAddNewClickedStrengths(View v) {
    // Inflate a new row and hide the button self.

    inflateEditRowStrengths(null);


    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}



// Helper for inflating a row
private void inflateEditRowStrengths(String name) {

    idCount++;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setId(idCount);


    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {

                comment = datasource.createComment(editText.getText().toString());

            }

        }
    });


    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            datasource = new CommentsDataSource(getBaseContext());
            datasource.open();

            List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

            for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++){
                inflateEditRowStrengths(values.get(i).toString());

            }



        }
    });


    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            datasource.deleteAllComments();

            List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
                inflateEditRowStrengths(values.get(i).toString());

            }
        }
    });



    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String toFind = editText.getText().toString();

            datasource.deleteComment(toFind);
            mContainerViewStrengths.removeView(rowView);



        }
    });



    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        editText.setText(name);
    } else {
        mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // A TextWatcher to control the visibility of the "Add new" button and
    // handle the exclusive empty view.
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mAddButtonStrengths.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (mExclusiveEmptyView != null
                        && mExclusiveEmptyView != rowView) {
                    mContainerViewStrengths.removeView(mExclusiveEmptyView);
                    editText.getText();
                }
                mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
            } else {

                if (mExclusiveEmptyView == rowView) {
                    mExclusiveEmptyView = null;
                }

                mAddButtonStrengths.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
        }
    });

    // Inflate at the end of all rows but before the "Add new" button


    mContainerViewStrengths.addView(rowView, mContainerViewStrengths.getChildCount() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentValues are used for inserting or updating, not for deleting. For the delete call you provide these three parameters:

- The table name
- The where clause
- The where clause arguments which replace the ?s in your where clause

So you need:

```
String where = SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT + " = ? ";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {comment};
database.delete(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, where, whereArgs);
```

As SQL, that compiles internally as:

```
DELETE FROM COMMENTS WHERE comment = 'the value of comment'
```

Note that you can put the argument directly in the where clause if you wish like:

```
String where = SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT + " = '" + comment + "'";
database.delete(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, where, null);
```

However it is best practice to use the ? style arguments when you can.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance I would say that this is the line with the problem:

```
database.delete(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT
            + " = " + values, null);
```

You should not pass the "values" object, instead pass the comment.